# Why does the vertice on the nose of my object won't move on the x axis?

Tags: vertices

I'm new-ish to Blender so I'm sorry if the way I'm describing my problem is poor. There are 2 vertices on top of each other and neither of them will move on the x axis. I tried to delete one of them but then it opens up a hole in my object so then I use the other vertice left and use the "new edge/face from vertices" from the vertex context menu. But even though it seems to overall fix the problem there is another problem I encounter when I move around the vertices, the new faces aren't connected to the faces around it so there are gaps/holes in my object and I don't know how to fix that either. Any help is appreciated.

(Blender file)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tIX08GEySc7eVIOxkoX49VFDCRt12uBN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome, can you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here. First thing you have 2 *Mirror* modifiers, remove one. The fact that the vertices can't move on X is because you've enabled the *Clipping* option, which makes the vertices stick to the mirror axis, but it's a good thing to keep it unless you have a reason not to:

[image]

Disable the remaining *Mirror* modifier for the moment, in order to see  the other problems, you have overlapping vertices:

[image]

To merge them, select all, press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* and increase the  *Distance* up to 0.01, it will remove the unwanted vertices:

[image]

Also, you have all these inner faces along the mirror axis, it's not good, remove them:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying! I will look at it and start fixing everything.